# Getting text from HTML and counting word by occurance

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I built a python code with BeautifulSoup to extract a lot of information like meta tags, title, and how many times a keyword appears.

I would like this software to read a certain URL, clean all comas, tags and blank spaces and then show me a list with the top 10 keywords that appear on the page, sorted by occurance.

I have already managed to get only the visible text from the page:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.' + domain
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

text = soup.find_all(text=True)

output = ''
blacklist = [
    '[document]',
    'noscript',
    'header',
    'html',
    'meta',
    'head',
    'input',
    'script',
]

for t in text:
    if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
        output += '{} '.format(t)

print(output)
```

But i also have to keep some other code to get other informations I want

```
title = (soup.title.string)
meta_tag = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'description'})
description = meta_tag['content']
noindex = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'robots'})
canonicalfind = soup.find('link', attrs={'rel': 'canonical'})
canonical = canonicalfind['href']
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to tokenize. I'd just use the [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/). Also look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tokenize-text-using-nltk-python/) package and then do a `.value_counts()` on that list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


domain = 'espn.com'

url = 'http://www.' + domain
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

text = soup.find_all(text=True)

output = ''
blacklist = [
    '[document]',
    'noscript',
    'header',
    'html',
    'meta',
    'head',
    'input',
    'script',
]

for t in text:
    if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
        output += '{} '.format(t)

print(output)



import nltk
nltk.download('all')

# Remove punctuation
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens_no_punc = tokenizer.tokenize(output.lower())

# Remove stop words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

cleaned_tokens = [ w for w in tokens_no_punc if w not in stop_words ]

# Top 10 words and the counts using pandas value_counts()
import pandas as pd
print (pd.DataFrame(cleaned_tokens)[0].value_counts()[:10])
```

**Output:**

```
print (pd.DataFrame(cleaned_tokens)[0].value_counts()[:10])
espn        61
fantasy     20
08          18
football    15
open        11
get         11
us          11
sports       9
2019         9
top          9
```

Comment: Thanks, man! It works like a charm but I still have 1 issue (pardon me cause i'm kind of a newbie with Python):

1 - I really need the "nltk.download('all')? 'Cause whenever I run the code it has to download some data, if I could threat it another way without downloading it every time.

Comment: Oh you should only need to do `nltk.download('all')` once (the first time). After that, you can simply remove it from the code

Comment: Thanks, chitown88. Really appreciate your help!